# How to implement a loop to make all possible combinations of a set of values in a vector?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have to pass a vector into a function in MATLAB. It has six elements and each element can take four distinct values. I need to make a loop that can cover all possible combinations.

Basically, the vector should take the values:

```
0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4

0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6

0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.8

0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 1.0

0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.4

0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6

...

...

1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I think that'll be 4^6 = 4096 combinations. I have to run the function for each combination. So how can I do the loop here? I tried a few nested loops, I can make one of the value change and cycle the position of that value, but that won't yield every combination. Help please?

On another note, will passing all these 4096 vectors sequentially into a function cause any problems? Like a system hang? (I use i5, 4 GB Ram).

For Matlab 7.9.0 (R2009b)

Comment: Why not doing it all inside the function ? Look at my answer, it's only two rows to add to the function (if you pass the original vactor).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save all the loops by:

```
data=0.4:0.2:1;
DupData=kron(ones(1,6),data);
DesResult=unique(nchoosek(DupData,6),'rows');
```

This will give you the vectors by the order you want, no loops...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just need to write a loop, one way is:

```
for i = [0.4 0.6 0.8 1];
    for j = [0.4 0.6 0.8 1];

    % work
    output = myfunction(whatever, args, i, j);

    end
end
```

During the loop, i and j will take the values in that array (0.4,0.6,0.8,1). If you want your iterator variables to take on integer values so that you can use them as an index for your output you could do something like this.

```
% out-of-loop variables
combo = [0.4 0.6 0.8 1]
output = zeros(length(combo)); % good coding practice to initialize variable outside of loop. 

for i = 1:length(combo);
    for j = 1:length(combo);

    % work
    output(i,j) = myfunction(whatever, args, combo(i), combo(j));

    end
end
```

No, running a 5000 long loop will not cause a hang up.

Comment: Thank you. I used 6 loops and used each loop variable as array element.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the `index`th element of this series, convert your index to a base-4 number.  Like this:

```
values = 0.4:0.2:1;
index = 2314;
base4representation = dec2base(index, 4, 6);  %Returns the string "210022"
bese4representation_vector = double(base4representation-'0');  %Returns the vector [2 1 0 0 2 2]
result = values(bese4representation_vector+1);  %Returns [.8 .6 .4 .4 .8 .8]
```

If you want you can put this into a loop to generate all 4096 values (start at 0).  Or you can generate them as you go.